# Form not posting all checked input checkboxes

Tags: html, django

I am trying to post all checked input checkboxes. The input field is generated by django's for loop as shown below.

From what I have found so far, the below should be working. I believe the issue may be in the fact that the input fields are generated through the forloop, if so, how can I get around this? For each value add to list and post with js?

## index.html

```
{% for q in list %}
    {% if forloop.last %}
        <form method="POST" name="selectedchecks"> {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="qblock">
                <label class="pure-material-checkbox">
                    <input class="selectedchecks" type="checkbox" name="choices[]" value="{{ q }}">
                    <span>
                        <p>{{ q }}</p>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

## views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    selected_list = request.POST.getlist('choices[]')
```

What happens is that only the first value of {{ q }} is returned if the first checkbox is selected, if any other checkbox apart from the first is selected, nothing is returned (empty list). Selecting all checkboxes also only returns the first value.

It should POST all selected checkbox values.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

The problem was that the form was being re-initialized for every loop iteration. Setting the `<form>` tag before the loop fixed the issue!